# Multiple tracking ID, multiple sites, one email report?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

I have a Google Analytics account which contained 10 sites. For each site it has individual ID (for example `UA-1000000-01`, `UA-1000000-02`, `UA-1000000-03`...).

So, is it possible to set an automatically weekly email report that contains all 10 sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible but you would need to use the Google Analytics API to pull in the information from the individual accounts and merge it yourself before generating the report off of it. The standard web interface only allows you to drill into one property at a time.

If you are not comfortable programming something to call the API there are a number of Excel sheets with plugins which will access Analytics for you and dump the information into a sheet for you. This is a simple way to get it all into a single place to report on.

Comment: the Google Analytics API thing seem hard for me. I wanna has this automatically send out a weekly email report.

Comment: Does Google Analytics API you mentioned is able to automatically generate a weekly email report in PDF format?

Comment: An API is an "application programming interface". It is basically just a way to allow one program to talk to another through a defined set of rules. You would have to do some programming for this to work for you which might not be what is appropriate to you. Check out some of the Analytics Excel plugins via Google as I think this might suit you best.

Comment: is it easier if all the sites are using same(one) tracking ID? If so, how can I get the one email report setup?

Comment: No each site should have its own unique property ID. How to get one email report setup is as per answered above.